# How can I change app badge count on Poco and Xiaomi phones such as Poco X3 NFC in Android studio

Tags: java, android, react-native, push-notification

I want to change the default count of the app icon badge on Android devices. I tried it with [ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/blob/master/README.md). It worked for Samsung and Zony XZ2 devices. I tried it with Xiaomi and Poco X3 NFC devices. It wasn't a success.

```
    package com.jkit.smartoffice;
    
    import static io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseApp.getApplicationContext;
    import com. Facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
    import com. Facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
    import com. Facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
    
    import me. lanolin.shortcutbadger.ShortcutBadger;
    
    public class NotificationModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    
        public NotificationModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
            super(reactContext);
        }
    
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "Notification";
        }
    
        @ReactMethod
        public void setBadge(int badge count) {
            try {
                ShortcutBadger.applicant(getApplicationContext(), badge count);
            } catch (Exception e) {
    
            }
        }
    
        @ReactMethod
        public void removeBadge() {
            try {
                ShortcutBadger.removeCount(getApplicationContext());
            } catch (Exception e) {
    
            }
        }
    }
```

These are the permissions I have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.BADGE_COUNT_READ" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.BADGE_COUNT_WRITE" />
<!--for Samsung-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE"/>
<!--for htc-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT"/>
<!--for sony-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE"/>
<!--for apex-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT"/>
<!--for solid-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE"/>
<!--for huawei-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<!--for ZUK-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE"/>
<!--for OPPO-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using some other library `BadgeHelper` or else implement the `badge count` feature natively which is using for the notification API from Android but the badge feature is not officially supported by android. you can try using the `BadgeHelper`